# he employs more than 1000 people,about 40 percent of whom he estimates are foreign-born

Tags: grammar

Extracted this from Times Magazine,and I am confused by the use of " about 40 percent of whom". Just couldn't seem to get this use of language.Would anyone explain to me this? And sometimes I read " of which", I often end up facing the same confusion.

Original text as below:

> As a philanthropist.Bacall has raised more than $10 million for his non-profit,which supports refugees,and as the CEO of Elite Hospitality Group,a development and management company,he employs more than 1000 people,about 40 percent **of whom** he estimates are foreign-born.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Why is this question not "he estimates are " - 2 verbs.

Comment: It'd great if you could explain what exactly you don't understand about this usage.

Comment: Is it that you don't understand what *of whom* or *of which* means?

Answer (score 1):

Your example is like this:

> He has five dogs, three *of which*, he says, know how to sing.

It is not like this:

> He has five dogs.<sup>(full stop)</sup>    Three *of them*, he says, know how to sing.

Note the differences.

When there is no full stop after **dogs**, the subsequent clauses belong to the same sentence and therefore a *relative pronoun*, namely **which**, is used to refer back to the five dogs.

Where there is a full stop after **dogs**, the subsequent clauses belong to a new sentence, and therefore a normal pronoun, namely **them**, is used to refer back to the five dogs.

NOTE:  The punctuation does not *cause* these syntactic relationships; it merely *reflects* them.